# Tomcat 7: process request out of band

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I'm trying to find a way to process HTTP requests programmatically with Tomcat 7 — "programmatically" meaning without actually making a TCP connection and sending the request.  Basically, if I have an HttpServletRequest, is there a way to get Tomcat to give me the corresponding HttpServletResponse?

I perused http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html but couldn't find any mention of this now.  One possibility is that [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) has a method service() that would work, so if I could get a reference to the servlet object itself I'd be all set.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to get that either.

I should note that the servlet in question is a Jersey 1.17 servlet, although I don't think that matters to the question I'm asking.  (Tomcat is clearly capable internally of dispatching a request based just on the URL, which is basically what I'm after here.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to forward a request to another servlet. Take a look at the [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) class and its `forward()` method. [Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher) are some explanations and examples.

Comment: Thanks @david-levesque, that sounds promising, but one thing trips me up: where do I get an HttpServletResponse object to pass to forward() (or include())?  All the examples I can find seem to involve passing the response object for the "outer" request, but I don't want the "inner" request I'm making to change that response directly.  I just want to get the information it returns and use it myself to build the outer response.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I did not understand your question correctly and I still don't. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've run into variations on this theme a few times, but my motivation at the moment is an attempt to create a Jersey resource that can batch up multiple requests.  For example, a client that is unable to use persistent connections for some reason can make a single request with a body that specifies multiple requests, and Jersey executes each one internally on the clients behalf and returns some sort of amalgamation of the responses.